# Problem running test command inside Docker container in a Gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm just getting started with `docker` and continuous integration with `Gitlab`. I've added the following `gitlab-ci.yml` file to the root of my repository:

```
# Official docker image
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

build-dev:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t obikerui/project -f app/Dockerfile.dev ./app

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run obikerui/project npm run test -- --coverage
```

The `build-dev` stage runs and passes but the `test` stage fails with the following error message:

```
$ docker run obikerui/project npm run test -- --coverage
Unable to find image 'obikerui/project:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for obikerui/project, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 125
```

Can anyone explain what's going wrong and suggest a fix? The repository is private, so do I need to provide some extra configuration to accommodate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each job runs in a different container. You build and you tag your image correctly but that stays in that container.

For the test job a new container starts and that one does not have the image build by the previous job.

You should push your image to a registry (after you tag it accordingly) and then the test job should use the image from the repository.

You can use a public registry like the one offered by Docker or you can run a local container based on the image registry:2 provided by docker. In this case you have to make sure that the domain name pointing to the registry is available on your network (it can be an nginx with reverse proxy)

Comment: You could also use the Docker registry that GitLab comes with anyways ([cf.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html#gitlab-container-registry)).

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get the runner working by using the Docker registry with Gitlab, as @bellackn commented.